# Como utilizar duas colunas do banco de dados como critério de ordenação de uma Query?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Olá,

Vocês poderiam me ajudar com esta dúvida? Estou fazendo uma `query` no MYSQL que precisa buscar no banco de dados registros e ordena-los por duas colunas diferentes utilizando `ORDER BY`. Estou usando a `query` a seguir, mas não funciona como o esperado.

```
SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY status = 'Desenvolvimento', created DESC limit $inicio, $quantidade_pg "
```

Para a coluna "status" tenho dois valores possíveis, "Desenvolvimento" e "Concluído". A ideia era ordenar os pedidos pelos "Desenvolvimento" e em seguida ordena-los pela coluna "created" que possui a data de criação do registro no banco de dados. Podem me ajudar com o caminho correto para isto? Preciso utilizar `subquery` para esse tipo de `query`? Lembrando, estou utilizando essa `query` dentro de um Javascript, por isso possui os cifrões nas variáveis inicio e quantidade_pg.

Comment: A sintaxe `ORDER BY X = Y` não existe. Se quer apenas ordenar pelo status, é apenas `ORDER BY status`; a parte da comparação, `= 'Desenvolvimento'`, está sobrando e não faz sentido aí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza essa instrução no seu Order by

```
...ORDER BY STATUS DESC, CREATED
```

Isso vai ordenar tudo pelo STATUS (DESC) primeiro, e depois pelo CREATED (ASC)